# Sobrepor uma página HTML com outra

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se é possível(e como fazer caso seja possível) sobrepor uma pagina HTML com outra e deixar o fundo escuro com uma opacidade baixa, como por exemplo aqui:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isso ai é feito com Bootstrap e chama-se modal. Pode ser feito com JavaScript.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta página: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: As pessoas tendem a esquecer-se que esses popups podem ser facilmente removidos no browser, por isso não esquecer que o html que está por trás continua a poder ser acedido, bem como quaisquer botões de submit, links, etc. Cuidado com as questões de segurança.

Comment: O segredo está nas DIV's e um pouco de Jquery. [Simples Tutorial de POP UP com divs](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-very-simple-popup-box-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o link com jQuery exemplo pronto e teste na própria pagina https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

**exemplo:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <style>
  body { font-size: 62.5%; }
  label, input { display:block; }
  input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
  fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
  h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
  div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
  div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
  div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
  .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
  .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
   </style>
   <script>
   $(function() {
  var dialog, form,
  
    // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
    emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
    name = $( "#name" ),
    email = $( "#email" ),
    password = $( "#password" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
    tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  
  function updateTips( t ) {
    tips
   .text( t )
   .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    setTimeout(function() {
   tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
    }, 500 );
  }
  
  function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
    if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
   o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
   updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
     min + " and " + max + "." );
   return false;
    } else {
   return true;
    }
  }
  
  function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
    if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
   o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
   updateTips( n );
   return false;
    } else {
   return true;
    }
  }
  
  function addUser() {
    var valid = true;
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  
    valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
    valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
    valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
  
    valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
    valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
    valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
  
    if ( valid ) {
   $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
     "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
     "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
     "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
   "</tr>" );
   dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
    return valid;
  }
  
  dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
   "Create an account": addUser,
   Cancel: function() {
     dialog.dialog( "close" );
   }
    },
    close: function() {
   form[ 0 ].reset();
   allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
  });
  
  form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
  });
  
  $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
  });
   });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
 <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
   <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
  
   <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  
    <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
  </fieldset>
   </form>
 </div>
  
  
 <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
   <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
   <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td>John Doe</td>
   <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
   <td>johndoe1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
 <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
  
  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Oi @FelipeAvelar obrigado por me ajudar a ajudar, fica melhor mesmo colocando tudo aqui, coloquei o código para executar aqui no SO também.

Comment: Uma explicação de como funciona o exemplo (ao menos a teoria por trás do exemplo) seria ótimo, pois outros usuários com a mesma dúvida irão se beneficiar dessa resposta.